# Drawing a number line

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-node

I am going through the TikZ tutorial in the manual, and I am trying to make my own examples. However, I cannot understand why my code is not woking as intended. I would like to draw a number line, with the numbers showing below the line at each tick. However, this is what comes out:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 3]

    \draw[<->, > = stealth, thick] (-2.8, 0) -- (2.8, 0); 
    \foreach \x in {-2, -1, ..., 2} {\draw (\x, 2pt)--(\x, -2pt);}
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1, ...,2} {(\x cm, 0) node[anchor = north]{$\x$};}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the format of the node command:

`\node at () {};`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 3]

    \draw[<->, > = stealth, thick] (-2.8, 0) -- (2.8, 0); 
    \foreach \x in {-2, -1, ..., 2} {\draw (\x, 2pt)--(\x, -2pt);}
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1, ...,2} { \node at (\x cm, 0) [anchor = north,shift={(0cm,-.2 cm)}]{$\x$};}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A better option with your `node` "inline" command,  could be:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 3]

    \draw[<->, > = stealth, thick] (-2.8, 0) -- (2.8, 0); 
    \foreach \x in {-2, -1, ..., 2} {\draw (\x, 2pt)--(\x, -2pt) node [below] {\x};}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also `anchor` option could just be skipped by using a taller "y shift" since we already used that!

Comment: Ah thanks; but I am a little confused, in the TikZ manual on page 44 they use the format (location) node {text}.

Comment: @Ovi ... this format is usually not a separate command, but an additional node somewhere (as far as I know) like: `\draw (x1,y1)--(x2,y2) node[above]{};` ... If the node is your basic command like in this case, I think the correct way is the "node" as `\node at () {};` ... See my edit too. Open on corrections from more advanced tikz users.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks again!

Comment: Just edited ... Check the last code. Welcome.

Comment: Since the last loop in the original code doesn't draw (strike the outline of) any shape, I'd use the `\path` command instead of `\draw`, like this: `\path (\x cm, 0) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};`. But `\draw` or `\node` are perfectly fine too; I'm simply saying that the most straightforward way to fix the original code appears to me to be “prepend a `\path` command.”

Comment: @frougon ... The last code seems more straightforward to me (because the coordinate needed is already there in the first loop and the second loop becomes unneeded, and also because uses the node as the client's format -and as yours-). Although your comment is useful in similar cases.

Comment: @koleygr What I meant by “most straightforward” is: “the simplest fix that changes the OP code into what he probably wanted to write.” But sure, the last code in your answer looks fine to me (not a Ti*k*Z expert either, BTW).